# Invalid column name 'textBox.Text'

Tags: c#, sql

I'm using Sql for the first time. I have a visual C# project and a form filled with text boxes. When I try to get the information form first and second text box to make a new save in the table, I recieve an error 'Invalid column name 'value from first text box.'' .
Here is the code I think will be needed to help me:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(global::DiplomaAssignment.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);
 string sql = "INSERT INTO StudentsTable (First_name,Second_name) values (" + textBox1.Text + ",'" + textBox2.Text + "')";
            SqlCommand executeSql = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            connection.Open();
            executeSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

I think the problem is in the sql string syntax, but as I mentioned before I'm new and can't understand the displayed error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO StudentsTable (First_name,Second_name) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
                                                                         ^                     ^ missing single quotes
```

Comment: Okay, I fix this. Now I have a grid on my form and when I recieve the pop up for adding the new record is done I still can't see the record in my grid.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your sql a bit here. I think its better to use string.format instead gluing sting together. See if following works:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO StudentsTable (First_name,Second_name) values (string.format("{0},{1}",textbox1.text.trim(),textbox2.text.trim()))";
```

Note that there could be syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to put `textBox1.Text` in single qoutes.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO StudentsTable (First_name,Second_name) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')"
```

It should work this way.